# All my elements, headings, buttons get misplaced when I zoom-out or zoom-in, this also happens when I switch to different browser

Tags: html

This happens whenever i zoom-in or zoom-out, the website gets messed up and just yeah- looks weird.
This also happens when I switch from browsers to browsers, such as chrome looks entirely different and firefox looks entirely different too.
This also happens when I go onto a different sized laptop/desktop.
Any help is appreciated.

Website getting messed up while zooming images here
[image]

Website looks perfectly fine, when its in normal position ie 100% zoom

[image]

Comment: Some browsers support some CSS features when some dont. Some dont at all, while some require some other css syntax for it to work. If you using pure CSS then i would recommend switching to less or sass (or similar) so syntaxe issue would be fixed. But the issue would remain that not everything works on every browser.

Comment: About the layout - There is a thing called 'responsive design' (research about it). Basically it means that on different devices (screen size) the site would adapt and still look good. Since you provided 0 code, we cant be sure what you done but i am assuming you did some static width px sizing, maybe some position absolute, etc.So when screen size changes then the content can not fit anymore. Research about responsive design

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)